# Change value after update of dropdown

Tags: php, opencart, dropdown

I have a dropdown for my product configurator where I can select a product. The selected product has additional information (Yes or No), which is shown when selecting the appropriate product. The product configurator has several products which can be choosen.

If one of the products has the additional information "No", then the final message is "No".

If I choose now a product where the information changes from No to Yes, then the final message should also change to "Yes" without a page refresh.

The select box code is as follows:

```
      <select name="<?php echo $ot['option_type']; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($ot['gp_child'] as $key => $child) { $child_id = $child['child_id']; ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $child_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $ot['option_type'] . '-' . $child_id; ?>" data-hide="<?php echo $child['child_to_hide']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
```

What I have to display the final message is:

```
    <?php if ($child['info'][$field_name] == 'No') { ?>
      <h5>Diese Produktekonfiguration ist für den CH-Strassenverkehr Zugelassen: <span class="red">No</span></h5>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <h5>Diese Produktekonfiguration ist für den CH-Strassenverkehr Zugelassen: <span class="green">Yes</span></h5>
    <?php } ?>
```

This works fine for the initial selected product, but of course doesn't change when I change the value in drop down. What do I need to add to make this working?

Additional Info - If I choose a different value in the select box then also the values in the following field is updated:

```
      <?php foreach ($gp_child_info as $field_name => $field_text) if($child['info'][$field_name]) { ?>
      <div><?php echo $field_text; ?>: <?php echo $child['info'][$field_name]; ?></div>
      <?php } ?>
```

This field $child['info'][$field_name] contains the Yes / No value which should trigger the final message.

There are up to 5 rows with pulldowns for choosing a product and each of them has the value Yes/No in the field $child['info'][$field_name]. So as soon as one of the rows has the value "No" the final message is also "No".

Result from print_r($ot['gp_child']);

Array ( [53] => Array ( [child_id] => 53 [info] => Array ( [product_id] => 53 [gp_parent_id] => 0 [name] => abart [description] => [meta_title] => test [meta_description] => [meta_keyword] => [tag] => 1234ZV [model] => test **[sku] => Yes** [upc] => [ean] => [jan] => [isbn] => [mpn] => [location] => [quantity] => -1 [delivery_days] => 14 [stock_status] => Nicht an Lager [image] => catalog/car-logo/abarth.png [manufacturer_id] => [manufacturer] => [price] => 100.0000 [special] => [reward] => [points] => 0 [tax_class_id] => 0 [date_available] => 2017-02-10 [weight] => 0.00kg [weight_class_id] => 1 [length] => 0.00cm [width] => 0.00cm [height] => 0.00cm [length_class_id] => 1 [subtract] => 1 [rating] => 0 [reviews] => 0 [minimum] => 1 [sort_order] => 1 [status] => 1 [date_added] => 2017-02-15 14:30:33 [date_modified] => 2017-02-17 17:17:22 [viewed] => 42 [stock] => Nicht an Lager ) [image] => Array ( [popup] => http://2302.speedone.ch/image/cache/catalog/car-logo/abarth-600x400.png [thumb] => http://2302.speedone.ch/image/cache/catalog/car-logo/abarth-50x50.png [swap] => http://2302.speedone.ch/image/cache/catalog/car-logo/abarth-50x50.png ) [name] => abart [attributes] => Array ( ) [price] => CHF 100.00 [special] => [tax] => CHF 100.00 [nocart] => [child_to_hide] => ) )

The value at the end which triggers the Yes/No message is the [SKU]

Comment: have you tried any javascript or jquery for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php is server side scripting language and that simply can't do this. What you need is client site programming.

One of them is jquery which would be more handy:

**HTML:**

```
<select class="select-name" name="<?php echo $ot['option_type']; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($ot['gp_child'] as $key => $child) { $child_id = $child['child_id']; ?>
    <option data-sku="<?php echo $child['info']['sku']; ?>" value="<?php echo $child_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $ot['option_type'] . '-' . $child_id; ?>" data-hide="<?php echo $child['child_to_hide']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
 </select>

<div class="message">
 <?php if ($child['info'][$field_name] == 'No') { ?>
  <h5>Diese Produktekonfiguration ist für den CH-Strassenverkehr Zugelassen: <span class="red">No</span></h5>
<?php } else { ?>
  <h5>Diese Produktekonfiguration ist für den CH-Strassenverkehr Zugelassen: <span class="green">Yes</span></h5>
<?php } ?>
 </div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
<script>
 $(".select-name").on("change",function(){
var length = $(".select-name option:selected[data-sku=No]").length;
if(length > 0) { // at least one is no
    $(".message").html("<h5>Diese Produktekonfiguration ist für den CH-Strassenverkehr Zugelassen: <span class='red'>No</span></h5>");
} else {
    $(".message").html("<h5>Diese Produktekonfiguration ist für den CH-Strassenverkehr Zugelassen: <span class='green'>Yes</span></h5>");
}
});
</script>
```

Working code snippet here:

```js
$(".select-name").on("change",function(){
    var value = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    if(value == "No") {
        $(".message").html("<h5>Diese Produktekonfiguration ist für den CH-Strassenverkehr Zugelassen: <span class='red'>No</span></h5>");
    } else {
        $(".message").html("<h5>Diese Produktekonfiguration ist für den CH-Strassenverkehr Zugelassen: <span class='green'>Yes</span></h5>");
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select-name" name="">
    <option selected>No</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
 </select>

 <div class="message">
  <h5>Diese Produktekonfiguration ist für den CH-Strassenverkehr Zugelassen: <span class="red">No</span></h5>
 </div>
```

Comment: I've tried your proposal, but this is not yet working. I've add some additional info on my initial post....thanks

Comment: have you added jquery file like http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js in your file?

Comment: the select box has not the a yes/no option. The select box contains information such as 'Product 1' and 'Product 2'. When I choose 'Product 1' additonal info such Yes or No are being shown. So this additional vaule must be verified and then the message needs to be changed accordingly. Can you help on that as well?

Comment: can you post the result of print_r($ot['gp_child']); on your question.

Comment: Works fine now for the first product entry. But when I change the second, then this has no effect. You might want to look at http://2302.speedone.ch/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=51&mfp=level%5B1%5D ...thanks

Comment: thanks for the quick update....So it's working almost as I would wish to. Initially I have a product with value No and one with Yes. Message is "No", which is correct. When I change option from Product 1 that the value becomes No, then the message is still "No", which is also correct. Change the value back for product one to have the value "Yes" again, then the final Message changes to "Yes" as well which is not correct, as the second product is still set to "No". Do you mind looking into this again? Otherwise great stuff...many thanks...

Comment: I don't mind mate..So it takes me long time to understand your question properly..So do you mean when both of the product set to 'yes' it should be yes, otherwise it should be 'no'..am I right ?